# Linq Query from textboxes that might be empty (Coalesce)

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, coalesce

I need to know if there is any way to coalesce this fields :

`String Field1`

`Integer Field2`

When user input is nothing on the textboxes, I need this query to ignore the values
but I dont know how to achieve it.

I used `Nothing`, `default nullable value` for integer using:

```
Dim nullInt As Integer?
        nullInt.GetValueOrDefault()
```

With no luck.

```
Dim veh As wsTarificador.Class1() =
    (From m In vehiculos
     Where m.Field1= IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCaballos.Text), nothing, txtCaballos.Text) _
     And m.Field2=Convert.ToInt32(IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPuertas.Text), nothing, txtPuertas.Text))
    Select m).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Dim veh As wsTarificador.Class1() =
    (From m In vehiculos
     Where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCaballos.Text) OrElse m.Field1 = txtCaballos.Text) _
     AndAlso (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPuertas.Text) OrElse m.Field2=Convert.ToInt32(txtPuertas.Text))
    Select m).ToArray
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm @Yuriy Galanter. Thanks